# Check if SQL query has succeed on Android SQLite

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I'm dealing with the execSQL function from Android SQLite API. Since I pass query as a parameter, I execute it straight through this function, so I'm not processing it (and I'd prefer not to do it) to know if we are CREATING, INSERTING, DELETING, ...

The point is: is there any generic way to know if the SQL execution has succeed?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) throws [SQLException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/SQLException.html) if the SQL string is invalid. You can also wrap your statement into transaction using the model:

```
   db.beginTransaction();
   try {
     ...
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
     db.endTransaction();
   }
```

Comment: As obvious as helpful. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I usually wrap my `try{...}finally{...}` blocks with a listener ( [`beginTransactionWithListener(SQLiteTransactionListener transactionListener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransactionWithListener%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteTransactionListener%29)), and use the `transactionListner` to check whether everything went well within the transaction, in addition to everything within the try/finally.